# What Should I be using here? Threading? Async?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am not sure what to use in this scenario.

I have an asp.net web api method that basically does this

1. Finds points of interests from foursquare near user.
2. Uses the foursquare locations to do queries in my database to find unique data about point of interest near user.

However since I need to store some of the foursquare information to link to my unique data to that location I decided to store all the information in my database and have my database act as my caching system.

This means anything new point of interest that comes in I have to insert into my database, check if it exists and if so then skip it or if it exists check the last refresh date(foursquare policy states all data must be refreshed after 30 day) and if it out past the refresh date I have to update the data.

I want to slow the user down and have to wait for the above to happen. I want my code to do step 1 and then do what I just mentioned while at the same time doing step 2.

Once step 2 finishes I want to return the data and let the user get on their way. If my caching system is not finished then it should keep going but not bog down the user.

I won't use any of these new results in step 2 as if I am inserting it then I won't have any data on that location at this time.

Not sure if I need to make a thread or use the async/await to achieve this.

**Edit**

Here is what I am trying to do

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    // this will do a foursquare lookup to find all stores near the user
    // I want to insert them into my database and link it to my unquie data. 
    // stores pulled from foursquare will
    // a) Be new and not in my database
    // b) exist in my database but have been refreshed lately
    // c) have not been refreshed in timeframe of foursquare policy
    // THIS SHOULD WORK IN THE BACKGROUND
    storeService.PointsOfInterestNearUser(80, -130); //As you can see it is 
                        //void. Not sure where to put the async/await stuff

    // find this product. Should be happening at the same time as above line.
    var product = productService.FindProduct("Noodles");

    //This will get returned to the user. 
    // the new stores taht are being added in StoreNearUser 
    //won't effect this search as I will have not data on this new store
    // if existing store is being refreshed it is possible old 
    //address might be picked up...
    //I can live with that as I doubt the address will change much.

    // this should happen after product
    var allStores = storeService.FindStoresThatHaveItem(product);

    // this should be returned as soon as above line is finished. 
    //If StoreNearUser is not done, it should keep going but not hold up user.
    return allStores;
}
public void StoresNearUser(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    // get all categories I can about in foursquare. 
    //First time from db otherwise cached.
    List<StoreCategory> storeCategories = GetStoreCategories();

    // do a request and get everything in near the user
    //(provided it is also in a category I care about)
    var request = CreateFoursquareStoreRequest
                       (latitude, longitude, storeCategories);

    // do the actual call.
    var response = client.Execute<VenueSearch>(request);


    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
// start going through the results, add or update or skip of entry will happen
        AddUpdateStores(storeCategories, response);
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(response.ErrorException);
    }
}
```

Edit 2

```
public async Task StoresNearUser(double latitude, double longitude)
{
// get all categories I can about in foursquare. First time from db otherwise cached.
    List<StoreCategory> storeCategories = GetStoreCategories();

// do a request and get everything in near the user(provided it is also in a category I care about)
    var request = CreateFoursquareStoreRequest(latitude, longitude, storeCategories);

    await client.ExecuteAsync<VenueSearch>
              (  request
                 , response =>
                     {
                         if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                         {
                             AddUpdateStores(storeCategories, response);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext()
                                        .Raise(response.ErrorException);
                         }
                     }
              );
}
```

gives me this error

```
Cannot await 'RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle'
```

I also don't get the difference between `Task` and `void`. From what I read if you just use `Task` it means you are sending nothing back of meaning, then why not just use `void`?

**Edit 2**
I found [this post](http://ianobermiller.com/blog/2012/07/23/restsharp-extensions-returning-tasks/) to show me how to make the wrapper for Restsharp. It is not 100% what I want but that is a separate issue.

```
public async Task StoresNearUser(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    List<StoreCategory> storeCategories = GetStoreCategories();

    var request = CreateFoursquareStoreRequest
                    (latitude, longitude, maxRadius, returnLimit, storeCategories);

    var response =  await client.GetResponseAsync(request);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
// had to use json.net right now as the wrapper does not expose restsharps deserilizer
        var venue = JsonConvert
                    .DeserializeObject<VenueSearch>(response.Content);
        AddUpdateStores(storeCategories, venue);
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext()
                   .Raise(response.ErrorException);
    }
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage>Get()
{
    await storeService.PointsOfInterestNearUser(80, -130);
    var product = productService.FindProduct("Noodles");
    var allStores = storeService.FindStoresThatHaveItem(product);
    return allStores;
 }
```

When I watch from the debugger it looks like it is still all going in order. I think `product` and `allStores` need to be since I need the product before I can find the stores but `PointsOfInterestNearUser` should be going at the same time as `FindProduct`.

**Edit 3**
Here is my FindProduct Method. Not sure what to make async to me it looks like everything needs to wait.

```
public ResponseResult<Product> FindProduct(string barcode)
    {
        ResponseResult<Product> responseResult = new ResponseResult<Product>();
        Product product = null;

        try
        {

            var findBarCode = context.Barcodes.Where(x => x.Code == barcode).Select(x => x.Product).FirstOrDefault();

            responseResult.Response = product;

            if (product == null)
            {
                responseResult.Status.Code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }
            else
            {
                responseResult.Status.Code = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            responseResult.Status.Code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            responseResult.Status.Message = GenericErrors.InternalError;
        }

        return responseResult;
    }
```

**Edit 4**

Still not sure how to do the Task.WhenAll()

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage>Get()
    {
      Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
      tasks[0] = storeService.PointsOfInterestNearUser(80, -130);
      tasks[1] = productService.FindProduct("Noodles");

       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

       // not sure how to get product back out. I looked in the debugger and saw a "Result" that has it but when I do tasks[1].Result inetllisene cannot find .Result
       var allStores = storeService.FindStoresThatHaveItem(product);
       return allStores;
     }
```

Comment: Sounds like a thread would work best. If you don't care about the returned info from the call for updating the db then why use async/await? Can you just fire and forget?

Comment: @KirkWoll: Not at all. `async` and `await` do not imply multithreading.

Comment: @Stephen, that's true, I forgot it could all happen on the same thread.  Oops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `async`/`await` for this. Updating a cache is one of the rare situations where returning early from an ASP.NET request is acceptable. You can see my [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) for some helpful code.

So, something like this (simplified to just look up one "interesting place" per location):

```
public async Task<PlaceWithData> FindPlaceAsync(Location myLocation)
{
  Place place = await GetPlaceFromFoursquareAsync(myLocation);
  PlaceWithData ret = await GetExtraDataFromDatabaseAsync(place);
  if (ret.NeedsRefresh)
    BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() => UpdateDatabaseAsync(place, ret));
  return ret;
}
```

You may also want to consider extending the ASP.NET caching system rather than doing a "roll your own" cache.

Comment: I think I have to give a code sample maybe that will show what I am doing more as I did think async was a good way to go but the problem I run into is it is basically void the method and it did not like that.

Comment: I reviewed your code sample. I recommend you first make it all `async` and only then change it to return early. When converting to `async`, I like to work from the inside out, so the first thing I'd look at converting is `client.Execute` (i.e., add a `client.ExecuteAsync`), and work your way up the call stack.

Comment: Ok I changed the client request to ExecuteAsync but I am not sure what you mean "make it all async". I am also using EF 5 and when I just make the client change I get this error now "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed." Normally it get disposed by ninject.

Comment: You need to `await` the call to `ExecuteAsync`, which means `StoresNearUser` should change from `void` to `async Task`, which means `Get` needs to `await` the call to `StoresNearUser`, which means `Get` should change from `HttpResponseMessage` to `async Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. Next (assuming these are hitting a DB backend), change your product/store services to be `async`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RestSharp, but it looks like ExecuteAsync is not a [TAP method (follow this link to see what that means and how to adapt other asynchronous systems to support TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). Regarding `async void` vs `async Task`, please read [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Hey. I updated my code but still not sure if it is working 100%.

Comment: If `FindProduct` is I/O-bound, then your next step is to make it `async`. Then you can use `Task.WhenAll` to do `PointsOfInterestNearUser` and `FindProduct` at the same time. Also be sure to read [my intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), and [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). Those will help you do `async` correctly.

Comment: Hi. I read your article a few times but still not 100% clear on async/await. I still have to go through the MSDN one but I am not sure what I could make in my FindProduct async to begin with. I posted added it to my OP.

Comment: I have an [`async` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that may help. It has some followup reading at the end.

Comment: That was the article I was referring too.

Comment: Also the only thing I can think of maybe awaiting is the EF call but it does not like that Error Cannot await 'Domain.Product'

Comment: I guess I have to wrap the EF statement or use EF 6? I am find with using EF 6 as this is just a personal project. However I don't see whereAysnc statement.

Comment: I believe the latest version of EF has some `async` support. I'm not familiar with the API, though; you'd have to do some searching to find out what exactly to use.

Comment: Yes EF 6 does but don't see an async where clause. Not sure how to convert it. How was it dones in EF 5? Did you wrap it around a task or something?

Comment: I've never used `async` database access with EF. Since you're on ASP.NET, wrapping it in a `Task` will not provide any benefit. As I said, I don't know how `async` works in EF and you'll have to search elsewhere for answers to that.

Comment: Ok. I think I have a way for EF but not 100% sure till I get "Task.WhenAll" working please see Edit4 to see where I am at with that.

Comment: `var task1 = storeService...; var task2 = productService...; await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); var product = task2.Result;`

Comment: Hmm I am just wondering if only "task2" should be in the Task.WhenAll(task2) as from playing around with Task.Delay I found that it will wait for task1 to finish before it would move on(what I thought might happen based on what I read in your blog). I rather have it still going in the background or something and return the results even if task1 is still going. I tired only do "task2" and now it returns the result before "task1" is finished but seems like "task1" never finishes now. Not sure if it is being killed once "task2" gets returned.

Comment: I actually don't think I need to bother with FindProduct method being async as I need that to wait for that one to complete before I can move on. So I just think the StoresNearUser needs to be async. This way both StoresNearUser and FindProduct happen at the same time but code has to wait till FindProduct finishes. Still not 100% with the leaving of method and why it kills StoresNearUser